# Using SafeArea in Dart/Flutter/AndroidStudio for Webview

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

In the Flutter code in Android Studio, I want to get Webview inside the safe view as it passes behind the status bar. How can use below code with SafeView widget? Thank you.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
getDeviceID();

if (deviceID == null) {
  deviceID = "unknown";
}

String webViewUrl = "https://xxx.xxx.com/login.aspx?deviceid=" + deviceID;
return WebviewScaffold(
    url: webViewUrl,
    withJavascript: true,
    withZoom: false
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put WebviewScaffold inside SafeArea Widget? i.e 
return SafeArea(child: WebviewScaffold() )

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you for quick response, Muhammad Usama siddiqui.